# How to create LVM physical volume from free space in a disk

Tags: partitioning, openstack, lvm

I have an external disk `sda` on the machine and I want to create an LVM physical volume from free space of the `sda`.
Here are the partition sizes:

```
 Name                     Flags                   Part Type             FS Type                            [Label]                       Size (MB)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                          Pri/Log              Free Space                                                            1.05              *
        sda1                     Boot                     Primary              xfs                                                                1073.75              *
        sda2                                              Primary              swap                                                               8456.77              *
        sda3                                              Primary              xfs                                                              107374.19              *
                                                          Pri/Log              Free Space                                                       383202.13              *
```

Actually, I want to create a `sda4` partition as LVM Physical Volume and create the LVM volume group on that. Can someone tell how can I do that?

I should mention that the goal is to set up a Cinder node for the OpenStack. According to the documentation, it should be done using the commands:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
vgcreate cinder-volumes /dev/sdb
```

But there is not a second disk `sdb` on my machine and I want to know how to do that using just the disk `sda`.

Comment: @Melebius I want to create LVM Physical Volume but the post is about Logical volume, isn't there any differences?

Comment: Creating a physical volume is just a part of the way, the linked answer shows all the operations you need to start using it.

Comment: @Melebius Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `/dev/sdb`, you can use a partition on your `/dev/sda` as a physical LVM partition but you have to create it first.

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:** Make a backup of the whole disk before modifying partitions on your hard drive.

If you can use GUI, [use GParted to create the new partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/380301/250300). Otherwise, run:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda
```

In the `parted` environment (indicated by the `(parted)` prompt), issue:

```
print free
```

Then issue the following command where `<START>` is replaced by the number given by the previous command as the start of the free space after `sda3`.

```
mkpart primary ext4 <START> 100%
```

Quit `parted`.

```
quit
```

Then you should be able to issue the commands:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sda4
sudo vgcreate cinder-volumes /dev/sda4
```